# Call "cellForItemAtIndexPath" before showing ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an app with custom calendar constructed from a `UICollectionView`. When I load a month for the calendar, I'd like to pre-load the previous and next months so that I can quickly swipe forward or back without delay.

Right now there's a delay in loading the next or previous months after swiping, and in instruments a lot of the delay is attributed to the `UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

**Is there a way to force that method to run without showing the view controller?** I need to do that for the previous and next months and that should reduce the transition time by about 400ms.

**Possible?** Thanks for your time

Comment: What are you doing in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` that is taking so long? Perhaps show that method

Comment: It's a few hundred inefficient lines of code, hah - can we pretend though that it's written perfectly and address the actual question I posed?

I'll optimize later, but I'm just curious about whether or not this is possible.

Comment: You can't invoke `cellForItemAtIndexPath` but you could pre-configure some cells and simply return then when the method is called.  Since you are dealing with easily computed data then this should be pretty simple.  This is the reason I asked about your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - it shouldn't be more than about 6-10 lines

Comment: You can call cellForItemAtIndexPath yourself, at some point in the view loading procedure, though I've never stopped to consider where.  Certainly by viewWillAppear it should be OK, not sure if OK in viewDidLoad.

Comment: While the OP could call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` they would still need to cache the result and return that result when the collectionView invokes `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - it is the invocation of the method from the collection view that counts and you can't force the collection view to do it before it is ready

Comment: To a point the collection view will automatically cache the results.  How much is hard to guess, however.

Comment: (Note that one should call the method on the collection view, not the data source.)